# How to fix this little problem with the intersection between the player and the rectangle?

Tags: intersection, p5.js

I'm coding this game, and I want the console to say **"fine"** every time you jump through the *blue rectangle*. and everytime you are passing through the *black one*, the console say **"dead"**. 
Everything was good, until I realized that if you are going through the *blue rectangle*, it says **"fine"** and after that **"dead"** even if you don't touch the *black one*.
I understood where was the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it.

Here is the [link](https://editor.p5js.org/AlexArek/sketches/rkoc4XA3m) (the intersection function is in the **player.js** file): https://editor.p5js.org/AlexArek/sketches/rkoc4XA3m

Comment: You'll have better luck if you narrow your problem down to a [mcve] instead of posting a link to your whole project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that I've fixed the problem, what you were doing was making a hitbox for each rectangle (gray and blue), and updating both of them without checking if the player is colliding with one. I re-did some of your code, and left comments to make it easier to get around.

Here's a link to my updated version: https://editor.p5js.org/JSproductions/sketches/SyxTyIyG6m

I hope you can finish what you're working on with this, good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I was looking for.